# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint, even though im not adding or modyfying anything in the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My program is parsing an xml file and adding orders from this file to the mssql database. Before he adds those orders to database he analyses them if there are any duplicates that need to be dealt with.

```
        foreach (var newOrderXml in newOrdersList)
        {                          
            var dupesInDb = _context.OrdersXml.Include(o=>o.OrderXmlItems)
                                              .Where(o => o.OrX_ORDERNR.Contains(newOrderXml.OrX_ORDERNR))
                                              .ToList();
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Program loops through all of the new orders in newOrderList and gets the list of duplicates with linq query. If there are 0 duplicates and nothing gets returned, everything works fine, but if a single duplicate is returned then SaveChanges method will throw an exception "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint PK_dbo.SewingCardBundles, Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SewingCardBundles'. The duplicate key value is (1).", even though im not adding or modyfying anything in the context. I dont really know what is happening, all im doing is getting, im not changing anything, im not creating new objects. This exception happens exactly at this spot, if i try to save changes before this linq query then nothing bad happens but if i try it after this linq query i get the exceptions. So where does those changes to context come from?

Here are my models:

```
public class OrderXml 
    {
        public OrderXml()
        {
            OrderXmlItems = new List<OrderXmlItem>();
        }

        public int OrX_Id { get; set; }
        public string OrX_ORDERNR { get; set; }
        public string OrX_REFERGB { get; set; }
        public int? OrX_CUSTOMERNUM { get; set; }
        public string OrX_DNAME { get; set; }
        public string OrX_DADR { get; set; }
        public string OrX_DPCODE { get; set; }
        public string OrX_POSTALCODE { get; set; }
        public string OrX_COUNTRY { get; set; }
        public string OrX_PHONE { get; set; }
        public string OrX_EMAIL { get; set; }
        public int? OrX_LANG { get; set; }
        public int? OrX_CUSTGRP { get; set; }
        public int? OrX_QUALITCON { get; set; }
        public string OrX_SHIPVIA { get; set; }
        public string OrX_DATE1 { get; set; }
        public string OrX_DATE2 { get; set; }
        public string OrX_DELIVGB { get; set; }
        public string OrX_SORT { get; set; }
        public int? OrX_CURLAB { get; set; }

        public List<OrderXmlItem> OrderXmlItems { get; set; }

        public Adress Adress { get; set; }
}


public OrderXmlItem()
        {
            SewingCardBundle = new SewingCardBundle();

        }

        public int OxI_Id { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_PRODUCT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_ORDERLINE { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_QUANTITY { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string OxI_TPFABNR { get; set; }
        public string OxI_TPFABDEF { get; set; }
        public string OxI_TPFABNAME { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CURDIR { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CURWIDTH { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CURHEIGHT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_WORKMETH { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_FOLDTYPE { get; set; }
        public decimal? OxI_FOLDFACT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CURBAND { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CURHEAD { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CURBOTSEAM { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_PACKWLEFT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_PACKWRIGHT { get; set; }
        public decimal? OxI_NRSTROL { get; set; }
        public decimal? OxI_NRSTROR { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_LINTYP { get; set; }
        public string OxI_LINCOL { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_EMBSORT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_EXTRA { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_PRODUCE { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_PACKSORT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CURMODEL { get; set; }
        public string OxI_BARCODE { get; set; }
        public string OxI_EXTRAINF { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_RAILTYP { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_RAILCONT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_RAILCONTSIDE { get; set; }
        public decimal? OxI_FABSTROTOT { get; set; }
        public decimal? OxI_FABSTROLEFT { get; set; }
        public decimal? OxI_FABSTRORIGHT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_FABUNDSIZ { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_FABTOTSIZ { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_LINSTROTOT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_LINUNDSIZ { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_LINTOTSIZ { get; set; }
        public decimal? OxI_FABWIDTH { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_CHILDSFT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_FOLDSORT { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_EMBLENGTH { get; set; }
        public int? OxI_PACKMETH { get; set; }


        public int OrderXmlId { get; set; }
        public OrderXml OrderXml { get; set; }


        public SewingCardBundle SewingCardBundle { get; set; }
    }


public class SewingCardBundle
    {
        public SewingCardBundle()
        {
            FlamanSewingCards = new List<FlamandzkaSewingCard>();
            FlamandzkaBrytaSewingCards = new List<FlamandzkaBrytaSewingCard>();
            OczkaSewingCards = new List<OczkaSewingCard>();
            OczkaBrytaSewingCards = new List<OczkaBrytaSewingCard>();
            WellenbandSewingCards = new List<WellenbandSewingCard>();
            WellenbandBrytaSewingCards = new List<WellenbandBrytaSewingCard>();
            PodwiazkaSewingCards = new List<PodwiazkaSewingCard>();
            TunelSewingCards = new List<TunelSewingCard>();
        }

        public int SwC_Id { get; set; }

        public OrderXmlItem OrderXmlItem { get; set; }

        public List<FlamandzkaSewingCard> FlamanSewingCards { get; set; }
        public List<FlamandzkaBrytaSewingCard> FlamandzkaBrytaSewingCards { get; set; }
        public List<OczkaSewingCard> OczkaSewingCards { get; set; }
        public List<OczkaBrytaSewingCard> OczkaBrytaSewingCards { get; set; }
        public List<WellenbandSewingCard> WellenbandSewingCards { get; set; }
        public List<WellenbandBrytaSewingCard> WellenbandBrytaSewingCards { get; set; }
        public List<PodwiazkaSewingCard> PodwiazkaSewingCards { get; set; }
        public List<TunelSewingCard> TunelSewingCards { get; set; }
    }
```

and my Fluent API configurations for those models:

```
     public class OrderXmlConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderXml>
            {
                public OrderXmlConfiguration()
                {
                    HasKey(o => o.OrX_Id);

                    Property(o => o.OrX_ORDERNR).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_REFERGB).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_CUSTOMERNUM).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_DNAME).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_DPCODE).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_POSTALCODE).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_COUNTRY).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_LANG).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_CUSTGRP).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_SHIPVIA).IsRequired();
                    Property(o => o.OrX_CURLAB).IsRequired();

                    HasMany(i => i.OrderXmlItems)
                        .WithRequired(o => o.OrderXml)
                        .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderXmlId)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);           
                }

            }

    public class OrderXmlItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderXmlItem>
    {
        public OrderXmlItemConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(o => o.OxI_Id);

            Property(p => p.OxI_Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(p => p.OxI_PRODUCT).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_ORDERLINE).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_QUANTITY).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_TYPE).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_CURDIR).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_CURWIDTH).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_CURHEIGHT).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_WORKMETH).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_FOLDTYPE).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_FOLDFACT).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_PACKWLEFT).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_PACKWRIGHT).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.OxI_BARCODE).IsRequired();


            HasRequired(i => i.SewingCardBundle)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal( s=> s.OrderXmlItem)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);


        }

    }

public class SewingCardBundleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SewingCardBundle>
    {
        public SewingCardBundleConfiguration()
        {

            HasKey(s => s.SwC_Id);

            HasMany(s=>s.FlamanSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c=>c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasMany(s => s.FlamandzkaBrytaSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c => c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasMany(s => s.OczkaBrytaSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c => c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasMany(s => s.OczkaSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c => c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasMany(s => s.WellenbandSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c => c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasMany(s => s.WellenbandBrytaSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c => c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasMany(s => s.TunelSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c => c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasMany(s => s.PodwiazkaSewingCards)
                .WithRequired(c => c.SewingCardBundle)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);


        }
    }
```

Comment: In your code you are only retrieving records from the database so you don't need to do `_context.SaveChanges();` you can remove that line

Comment: i know, its there for better understanding of my problem, my problem is that later in calling _context.SaveChanges(); and it throws and error i mentioned before, because a linq query in my example is changing something in my context and i dont know what and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are calling `SaveChanges` in the first place (it is not needed), but once you get your data from database, context will track them (i.e. have them cached).

Since, you haven't specified `AsNoTracking` in your query, `SaveChanges` method will try to save entities which are being tracked which will lead to your "primary key violation" exception.

To circumvent the issue, you can just specify `AsNoTracking`:

```
var dupesInDb = _context
   .OrdersXml.Include(o=>o.OrderXmlItems)
   .Where(o => o.OrX_ORDERNR.Contains(newOrderXml.OrX_ORDERNR))
   .AsNoTracking()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: in my normal program im calling the savechanges method much later, but i wanted to show it that the exception is happening after this particular linq query. Could you explain to me why is EF trying to save those entities if no changes were made to them? I thought only edited or added entities are saved, why simple act of getting entities could trigger contex to try and save a duplicate of them?

Comment: It seems that some part of your code changes entity after fetch, you can use [DbChangeTracker](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx) to investigate current state of your entity (before Save) or you can just debug to see current entity state

Comment: Thanks for help
What is happening is weird, context is downloading SewingCardBundle  entity (which is a property of OrderXmlItem entity) from database, gets all its values and gets its IDs from database, but treats it as if its a new  entity (status: added) that has been added to db and when he tries to save changes it throws exception becasue there alredy are entities in db with the same id key.Maybe i need to change my linq query so it would eagerly load SewingCardBundle entity and not just OrderXmlItems entity?

Comment: I noticed this happens when i use eager loading but doesnt happen when i use lazy loading. Can anyone explain to me why it happens?